# Creating LINQ from SQL

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, ado.net, linq-to-dataset

I am trying to create Linq query from following Sql but not able to get it work.

**SQL**

```
"select distinct(roomName) as RoomName, tblroomid as RoomId
 from TblMaster,tblrooms 
 where tblrooms.tblroomid = TblPresentationMaster.tblroomid 
 and convert(datetime, PDay, 101)='" + Pday + "'";
```

**LINQ**

```
(from tblRoom in tblRooms.AsEnumerable()
 join tblPMaster in tblMaster.AsEnumerable()
 on tblRoom.Field<int>("tblroomid") equals tblPMaster.Field<int>("tblroomid")
 where tblPMaster.Field<string>("pday") == Pday 
 select tblRoom.Field<string>("roomName")).Distinct();
```

If I try to run it

```
foreach (var myReader in query)
{
}
```

I am getting following error

> Specified cast is not valid.

These are values in following variable, hope this help in catching error

```
tblPMaster.pday = Jun 28 2011 12:00AM
Parameter Pday = 28/11/2011
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong. Can someone please help in getting correct LINQ query?

Comment: What specific problems are you having with that code?

Comment: @Servy sorry i missed the error detail, now i have added it.

Comment: The exception is telling you that one of your types is wrong.

Comment: What type is `Pday`?

Comment: @Jason, i have tried to find but cant figure it out, also i added the values in variable, to have proper idea.

Comment: @GertArnold, sorry for not giving full information, i have added it now

Comment: One of the `Field<T>`  calls doesn't have the right type.

Comment: Replace: `string` in `tblPMaster.Field<string>("pday") == Pday` with `DateTime' ;)

Comment: Hi @MaciejLos,  
i tried your suggest tblPMaster.Field<DateTime>("pday") == DateTime.Parse(Pday) or tblPMaster.Field<DateTime>("pday") == Pday, i am getting following error "Opertor == cannot be applied on operant system.datetime and string.

Comment: @javadotnetcoder, i suspect that converstion from string to datetime is impossible for set of reason, for example the field contains: null, not proper datetime string, etc. You need to check if returned value is null. BTW: Sorry, but it's poor idea to store date data type as a string.

Comment: It would be good to see your testing data. Please, create .net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and paste link to it.

Comment: @MaciejLos , i dont have control over database, it is like that, date is stored in field having varchar type, one thing is sure, it dont have Null values, i will try to created this particular module and put the link here.

Comment: @MaciejLos also i am just thinking why the Linq is so complex that even though we are having the working SQL version then too we cant create the Linq from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@javadotnetcoder, thank you for clarification. I think i found a solution...

Try it:

```
DataTable tblMaster = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("pday", Type.GetType("System.String"));
tblMaster.Columns.Add(dc);
tblMaster.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"Nov 28 2011 12:00AM"});
tblMaster.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"Apr 27 2013 11:10PM"});
tblMaster.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"Jul 18 2011 12:00AM"});
tblMaster.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"Mar 19 2012 10:01PM"});

DateTime PDay = new DateTime(2011,11,28);

//foreach(var row in tblMaster.AsEnumerable())
//{
//  Console.WriteLine("{0}", Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]));
//}

var qry = tblMaster.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(p=>Convert.ToDateTime(p.Field<string>("pday"))==PDay);
//qry.Dump();
```

Above code has been tested on LinqPad. Works as well ;)

Cheers, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

cast this to date not to string

```
tblPMaster.Field<string>("pday")
```

Comment: Did you mean `tblPMaster.Field<DateTime>("pday")` then?

Comment: yes. i dont know yet though if it works. im not on my computer atm. but kindly try it. :)

Comment: in addition. there is a two case on your problem. its either the casting or the data you are trying to cast. eg(casting a double data to a datetime) throws the error cast is not valid

Comment: Hi @syverrodriguez, i tried your suggest tblPMaster.Field<DateTime>("pday") ==   DateTime.Parse(Pday) or tblPMaster.Field<DateTime>("pday") ==  Pday, i am getting following error  "Opertor == cannot be applied on operant system.datetime and string.

Comment: @javadotnetcoder. have you tried using single equal sign? make sure to parse both sides to datetime. but sometimes other error occur when you try to parse string to date. eg. when it is null or invalid date. its really a headache.

Comment: @syverrodriguez  i tried it is not working, same error. I hope you are taking care then "Pday" field is of string type due to which in Sql i used the convert function.